# Google Indexed Pages with currency USD, not with default currency set GBP?

Tags: indexing, multicurrency

[image]
For my website: https://www.blazesunglasses.com/ , I have set default currency GBP but Google is indexing & caching pages with USD prices.

I want to index site with GBP currency set.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: R u using GeoIp Based Redirection?

Answer (score 0):

When I open the page, it is automatically in Euro. You must have a mechanism that decides this (maybe by IP?), and this mechanism treats the Google Bot as American. Either turn it off, or make it exclude the Google Bot:

```
<?php
$isGoogleBot=(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Googlebot') !== false);
if(!$isGoogleBot) {
    // currency switching stuff here
}
```